# Symfony2 Doctrine Metadata Cache with Redis Issue

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, redis

I'm trying to use Redis as a driver for caching doctrine metadata, query and results. Follwing is my configuration.

```
auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    result_cache_driver:
        type: redis
        host: %redis_host%
        instance_class: Redis
    query_cache_driver: redis
    #metadata_cache_driver: redis
```

When I remove the comment from line #metadata_cache_driver: redis, I get an error running a test I have with following error.

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory::wakeupReflection() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\ClassMetadata, string given, called in vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php on line 214

My Functional Test looks like Following:

```
public function testX()
{
    //The data in prepared in setup..
    $param1 = 'test-id';
    $param2 = 'test-key';
    $result = $this->em->getRepository('MyBundle:Test')
            ->findOneByXX($param1, $param2);
    $this->assertTrue($result instanceof Test);
}
```

And My Query looks like following:

```
$qb->select('c')
       ->from('MyBundle:Test', 'c')
       ->where('c.id = :id')
       ->andWhere('c.key = :key')
       ->setParameter('id', $id)
       ->setParameter('key', $key);

    $query = $qb->getQuery()
            ->useResultCache(true);

    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Do I need additional configuration for Redis? Any Help would be appreciated??

Answer (score 0):

I believe to resolve this you need to set the serializer for redis, the default serializer is probably not aware of the the PHP classes and when the object is removed from cache, and unserialized, it is not the same type as it was prior to serialization.

```
$redis->setOption(\Redis::OPT_SERIALIZER, \Redis::SERIALIZER_PHP);
```

For you case you will probably need to set the configuration option as a part of the driver configuration.